# Game theory - ranking of n players playing matches with m (>2) players each

Tags: combinatorics, game-theory

I am facing the following problem:

In two player games, a ranking of a pool of `n` players can be achieved by letting everyone play against every opponent, taking the result of each match and aggregate it to get the overall ranking. However, in my case a single match is played by `m` (e.g. 6) players. Every player is getting a score after a match. What would be a fair 'tournament format' that can be adjusted based on the total player count `n` and player count per match `m` to rank all the players from best to worst overall in a fair way?

I was searching for research in this area, but i am unable to find something fully covering this topic. I am probably using the wrong keywords. Can someone steer me in the right direction or suggest a solution to this problem? Thanks.

Comment: If you consider a fair tournament one in which the best players get to the end. Then what you seem to be looking for is a setup like Olympic running or swimming. Something like  heats > quarter-finals > semi-finals > finals, where only the top $x$ number of players move on.

Comment: Yes, i have considered various knockout formats. However, i thought of a different kind of format in which players are not eliminated after playing badly at one match. E.g. a season in football is also not played in a knockout tournament. Everyone plays against each opponent, even twice. Therefore, i was wondering whether there exists research in this kind of area. The count of total matches played is secondary.  Is there a way to quantify the balance / fairness of tournament formats for `m` player games?

Comment: This does not seem to be a mathematical problem unless you give a mathematical definition of "fairness".

Comment: Are m players competing against each other ('m teams of one player' in a battle royale style matches)? Depends on your game. You could look at how Esports Tournaments are held for battle royale games.

Comment: Yes, that is kind of the game mode. Currently, my solution to this problem is the random generation of `g` groups while making sure each player plays the same amount of games. Therefore, the aggregated score can be compared across all players. Sure, this can lead to similar setups, however by increasing the number of games played the score should converge to the true ranking of all players.